# SQL Server : ignore AVG NULL value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, average

```
Select AVG(Salary) from Employee
```

Output: `NULL`

When I want to convert the incoming value to an integer or a decimal, I get an error:

> Input string was not in a correct format

Comment: What are the sample data and the expected output?

Comment: You must be converting the `NULL` to a string with the value `'NULL'` somewhere? Just don't do that. Show the full code that gives this error. As `NULL` is a valid return value you should be using nullable types in .Net that can accept `null` as a value

Comment: @marc_s - "Input string was not in a correct format" would be coming from `int.Parse` or similar in .net - not SQL Server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aggregate functions such as `AVG()` ignore `null` values. So the result that you are getting indicates that:

- either `salary` is `null` on *all* rows of the table
- or the table has no row at all

If you want in that event to return something else, like `0`, use `COALESCE()`:

```
Select COALESCE(AVG(Salary), 0) from Employee
```